# AWS S3 Folder wise metrics

Tags: amazon-s3, monitoring, prometheus, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

We are using grafana's cloudwatch data source for aws metrics. We would like to differentiate folders in S3 bucket with respect to their sizes and show them as graphs. We know that cloudwatch doesn't give object level metrics but bucket level. In order to monitor the size of the folders in the bucket, let us know if any possible solution out there.
Any suggestion on the same is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon CloudWatch provides **daily storage metrics** for Amazon S3 buckets but, as you mention, these metrics are for the **whole bucket**, rather than folder-level.

[Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) can provide a **daily CSV file listing all objects**. You could load this information into a database or use Amazon Athena to query the contents.

If you require storage metrics **at a higher resolution than daily**, then you would need to track this information yourself. This could be done with:

- An Amazon S3 Event that triggers an AWS Lambda function whenever an object is created or deleted
- An AWS Lambda function that receives this information and updates a database
- Your application could then retrieve the storage metrics from the database

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply John,

However I found a solution for it using an [s3_exporter](https://github.com/ribbybibby/s3_exporter). It gives metrics according to size of the folders & sub-folders inside S3 bucket.